# Conditional group by aggregations in SQL (Hive)

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

Consider a table `USER_SITE` with the following columns:

```
user, site, n_visits, n_purchases
```

where the table above records one row for each user-site combination.

I would like to calculate the following info:

```
site, n_users_who_visited_the_site, n_users_who_made_purchases_on_the_site
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL? I tried drafting a few group by operations with no luck, but maybe I am missing something.

---

Example given `USER_SITE`:

```
user       site   n_visits  n_purchases
Julie   foo.com         3             0
Carry   bar.com         1             0
Emily   foo.com        10             1
Chris   zoo.com         5             3
```

We get:

```
site      n_users_who_visited_the_site  n_users_who_made_purchases_on_the_site
foo.com                              2                                       1
bar.com                              1                                       0
zoo.com                              1                                       1
```

Comment: Seems like aggregation should handle this... Have you tried using `sum`?  `Count` might work depending on your data.  Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: You keep editing your question -- sample data; desired results -- then we can help...

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes I apologize for the delay. I think the example above captures exactly the problem I am trying to solve. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example using `sum` with `case`:

```
select site, 
     sum(case when n_visits > 0 then 1 else 0 end) n_users_who_visited,
     sum(case when n_purchases > 0 then 1 else 0 end) n_users_who_made_purchases
from user_site
group by site
```